# SBT SFTP resolver not trying hard enough

Tags: sbt

I am converting our mixed build environment into an sbt based ecosystem.  And I am at a bit of a road block with this issue.

I have deployed a library to a remote repository via sftp but when I try to load it as a dependency I have an issue.

In build.sbt I have:

```
resolvers += {
  val privateKeyFile = new java.io.File(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
  Resolver.sftp("MY REPO", "aHost", "/repoBase/") as ("aUser", privateKeyFile)
}
```

update in interactive shows:

```
[info] Resolving com.test.it.out#myLib_2.11;1.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.test.it.out#myLib_2.11;1.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/bday/.ivy2/local/com.test.it.out#myLib_2.11/1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.test.it.out#myLib_2.11/1.0/jsshfs_2.11-1.0.pom
[warn] ==== MY REPO: tried
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

It never lists any path information for MY REPO.

I have tried multiple ways to configure the resolver, even users/hosts that should fail and the results don't change.

> show resolvers
>   [info] List(SftpRepository(MY REPO,SshConnection(Some(KeyFileAuthentication(aUser,/home/aUser/.ssh/id_rsa,None)),Some(aHost),None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(), artifactPatterns=List(/repoBase/[organisation]/module(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-revision.[ext]), isMavenCompatible=true, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)))

I did see someone had the same issue and said switching from SSH to SFTP fixed it, in 12.?.  I am using 13.7

I have come to the end of the internet on this one, please extends it a bit.

Thanks!

Comment: I can define the resolver the same way in the library project and publish to it, so I guess there is no real problem with it.

Comment: Here is a stupid work around!

Comment: Using ssshfs mount remote repo: /MY_REMOTE_REPO

Comment: (I guess these are one liners)   resolvers += "My REPO via sshfs" at "file:///MY_REMOTE_REPO"    That sucks, I have to set that up for everyone.  Not going to cut it long term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar issue, it was not listing any urls that it tried. I added the same `Pattern` that I was using while publishing, and it fixed the problem. Also, I have put my resolver as the first one in the order.

```
resolvers in ThisBuild := (Resolver.sftp("MY Repo", "example.com", 22, "sbt-repos/releases")(Patterns("[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"))) +: resolvers.value
```

I am using `0.13.9`. I searched a lot for this one and finally figured it out after so many trials. Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: I will have to get around to trying this again some day.  I have just been working around it by syncing the repository back locally using rsync.

Answer (score 0):

```
val sftpRes = {
  val privateKeyFile = new java.io.File(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
  Resolver.sftp("REPO", "gitHost", "/path/to/data/")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) as ("user", privateKeyFile)
  }

publishMavenStyle := false

publishTo := Some(sftpRes)
```

Using SBT 1.2.4

In the end this is what I got to work.  I tried Resolver.mavenStylePatterns, but in that case as with others SBT never really tries to find files on the resolver.

Using Ivy patterns on the publish and resolve worked for me.